# Converting a string of numbers to correpsonding letters

Tags: python, converters

For a project I am working on, I need to be able to convert a string of numbers into letters to form the correct words.  For example, I would need to convert 2626 into BFBF, but how would I make sure it does not turn into ZZ instead or vice versa.

I am extremely confused because I cannot think of any way to make this possible, and I need this program to convert the numbers into their original letters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I am not really sure what to do anymore…

Thanks you!

EDIT:  It seems as though this is impossible without using a list of numbers, so now I need to find a way to replace my strings with lists.  The problem is that I am making a public key cryptography encryptor/decryptor and I do not know how to do math on numbers without them being a string. (It wouldn't work for a list, for example if I had to square a number, 1212, I can easily do so with 1212^2.  However if the list was [12,1,2], I do not know how to square it to get the same answer as 1212^2.)

Any help would be great, Thanks Again!

Comment: Use a list, e.g. [2, 6, 2, 6], otherwise there is no way to reliably differentiate between combination of digits such as [26, 26] vs. [2, 6, 2, 6].

Comment: Once you use a list, use `chr()` to convert. `chr(65) = 'A'` and `chr(90) = 'Z'`

Comment: So there's no way of doing it using integers?
My project is a public key encrypted and decrypted, but on a very small level.  First, the user enters their secret code.  I then convert their code into numbers using (a=1,b=2, etc…) and then raise it to a power with a mod base etc. with the other steps to public key.  Then, with the encrypted message, the code continues public key to undo the message, and finding the number representation of the letters, which I have done.  The final step is converting these numbers into their original numbers, which I cannot find out how to do.

Comment: If you can use a delimiter between integers yes, otherwise you'll have problems.

Comment: @Alexander I understand what you're saying, but please check out my most recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using [chr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) you can convert an int to a letter, ex. `print chr(97)` prints `a`.
If you can use some symbol to identify groups, maybe '-', between numbers, then this is a simple problem.  If not you will run into ambiguous mappings as you mentioned.

For example you could create a number to letter dictionary:

```
alphabet_dict = {}
for abet in range(1, 27):
    alphabet_dict[abet] = chr(96+abet)

print alphabet_dict
```

prints:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
```

Now if we decide we can use a symbol delimiter, then we can use built in [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to break up our string into a list and then map those values (numbers) into the alphabet using the dictionary above:

```
s = '2-6-2-6'
def convert_num_to_alpha(num_string):
    num_list = num_string.split('-')
    abet_string = ''
    for num in num_list:
        abet_string = abet_string+alphabet_dict[int(num)]
    return abet_string 

print convert_num_to_alpha(s) # prints: bfbf
print convert_num_to_alpha('26-26') # prints: zz
```

**EDIT: How to convert the string of number-number (e.g. '2-6-2-6') to int**:

This is hackish but if you need to do arithmetic on the number, which I have stored as a string you can do something like:

```
print int('2-6-2-6'.replace('-', ''))  # prints: 2626
```

Comment: I see how that works, but like I said in my most recent edit:
(It wouldn't work for a list, for example if I had to square a number, 1212, I can easily do so with 1212^2. However if the list was [12,1,2], I do not know how to square it to get the same answer as 1212^2.)

Comment: @Flo my example only uses a list as an intermediate step to manipulate each individual number between `-`.  In my edit I show how you could get the integer from such a string.

Comment: @Flo in general it seems like this approach (your encrypt/decrypt) may need another look.  Perhaps you should post, in another question, your full problem, how you are currently approaching it, list the pitfalls, and how to fix them.  Be aware, don't ask too many questions in one post and steer clear of asking for advise.  State what is broken and ask how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will most likely post another post that goes into more depth about my problem.
As for your edit, I see how you converted the list into an integer, but after you do the arithmetic, it would be impossible to revert it into the correct integers, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Flo My pleasure to help (or try).  Just to be clear, the edit is converting a **string** to an integer, not a list.  As far as modular arithmetic and finding the 'correct' integers after, you're using a many to one function so there is no way to distinguish between any numbers mapped to a particular equivalence class, so you're right.

Comment: In case you are curious, I found a way to fix it using a method similar to the one you proposed.

Comment: @Flo Definitely, what did you do?

Comment: I used str.zfill(2) so that all the letters would be represented by 2 number; a = 01, b = 02, etc…
Then, instead of doing the arithmetic to all the numbers in one string, I kept it as a list and did the same math to each element of the list.  From that I could easily make it into one string to get the "encrypted message", or just continue decrypting it as a list, which would be able to differentiate between letters because each one is represented by 2 unique numbers.  Seems so obvious now, but that is how coding is!

Comment: @Flo Nice idea.  It does seem as though things are so much easier once you figure them out...By the way, it is perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question and then accept it.  Of course your solution will still be open to scrutiny from others.

Comment: By the way, I just asked another question regarding another problem I encountered with the same program.. Mind checking it out?

Comment: @Flo Looks like someone already got to it.  By the way, if you look at how I made the dictionary above `for abet in range(1, 27):
    alphabet_dict[abet] = chr(96+abet)` this is exactly what you need.  I made that dictionary to serve as a look up 'table' to map between integer (1 through 26) to alphabet letters (a through z).